# Woocommerce similar subcategories (Men -> Shirts | Woman -> shirts )

Tags: woocommerce, categories

I am currently developing my webshop product page. I have setup some different categories:

> - Men
>
>   - Shirts
>   - Socks
>   - Hoodies
> - Woman:
>
>   - Shirts
>   - Socks
>   - Hoodies

Now i would like to retrieve al shirts, socks and hoodies on my catalog independent 'Men' or 'Woman'. I have some hard time merging two sub-categories.

This is what i want to receive:

**Shirts**

- All shirts (men and woman)

**Socks**

- All socks (men and woman)

This is my code

```
    <section id="products">
            <?php
                $taxonomy  = 'product_cat';
                $orderby  = 'name';  
                $show_count   = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
                $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
                $title  = '';  
                $empty  = 0;

                $args = array(
                        'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                        'orderby'      => $orderby,
                        'show_count'   => $show_count,
                        'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                        'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                        'title_li'     => $title,
                        'hide_empty'   => $empty
                );

                $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

                foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
                        if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
                            $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
                            echo '<br /><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>'; 

                            $args2 = array(
                                    'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                                    'child_of'     => 0,
                                    'parent'       => $category_id,
                                    'orderby'      => $orderby,
                                    'show_count'   => $show_count,
                                    'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                                    'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                                    'title_li'     => $title,
                                    'hide_empty'   => $empty
                            );
                            $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
                            if($sub_cats) {
                                foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
                                    echo  '<h2>' . $sub_category->name  . '</h2>';
                                $args3 = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'product',
                                    'stock' => 1, 
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'product_cat' => $sub_category->slug,
                                );
                                query_posts($args3);
                                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                    ?>
                                        <div class="product">
                                                    <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                                        <?php
                                                if (has_post_thumbnail()) :
                                                    the_post_thumbnail('product-preview');
                                                endif;
                                            ?>
                                                        <span class="product-name"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                                            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
                                            </div>
                                    <?php
                                    endwhile;
                                wp_reset_query();
                                echo '</div>';
                                    }   
                            }
                        }       
                }

                    ?>
        </section>
```

Comment: What about using tags? All socks could be tagged with socks, men's or women's.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however using tags is not really user friendly.  I want to keep the backend clean and simple.  No worries, I already found a working method :)

Comment: Hope you will post your solution.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply. I just created a custom field in the backend for products with a dropdown ('men', 'woman', 'unisex'). You could even use Custom field suite if that is helpfull for you.     

With this approach you won't have any double categories.

Comment: Not sure I see how this is an improvement over tags, but thanks for replying with your solution.